# Couchbase with PHP GeoLocation Search - (Part) Solution

Tags: php, latitude-longitude, couchbase

**Problem**

I was in need of a search by range of distance from latitude and longitude. This was relatively straight forward in SQL, however, in couchbase I came across some difficulty. I eventually discovered that spatial views offer a solution for this, however the spatial views aren't accessible via the PHP SDK (yet) and so you had to use the REST Api as an alternative.

**Solution**

I can get a result set within a range from a latitude and longitude using this method, but now need to sort by date created. Please see end of this post.

My documents are as such:

```
{
    "docType" : "post",
    "title" : "Test post",
    "location" : {
        "latitude" : 1.123456789
        "longitude" : -13.9876543210
    }
    "created" : 1395329441
}
```

The trick is to create an index with a normal view which will format the keys in a specific way.

**The formula**

1. Preppend all keys with "point::"
2. Add a positive or negative sign "+", or "-"
3. Make the integer part 3 characters long by prepending with "0"s
4. Make the decimal part 9 characters long by appending with "0"
5. Repeat for both latitude and longitude

Example of a Key produced from the document above:

```
"point::+001.123456789,-013.987654321"
```

This will give you a key formatted in a way that will be sortable by the unicode collation which couchbase use.

**The View**

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(meta.type == "json" && doc.docType == "post" && doc.location){
    if(doc.location.latitude && doc.location.longitude){

      var prefix = "point::";
      var latitude = doc.location.latitude.toString();
      var longitude = doc.location.longitude.toString();

      var pointKey = prefix.concat(buildKey(latitude), ",", buildKey(longitude));

      emit(pointKey, meta.id);

      function buildKey(coord){       
        // positive or negative sign
        var sign;

        if(coord.substring(0,1) == "-"){
          sign = "-";
          coord = coord.substring(1, coord.length);
        } else {
          sign = "+";
        } 
        // remove "+" (incase it is there), though normall this isnt expressed
        if(coord.substring(0,1) == "+"){
       coord = coord.substring(1, coord.length);
        }

        var intSize = "000";
        var decSize = "000000000";

        // get integer and decimal parts of latitude
        var parts = coord.split(".");
        var int = parts[0];
        var dec = parts[1];

        // prepend int with 0's so it has a length of 3
        if(int.length < intSize.length){
          int = intSize.substring(0, intSize.length - int.length) + int;
        }
        int = int.substring(0,3);

        // append dec with 0's so it has a length of 9
        if(dec.length < decSize.length){
          dec = dec + decSize.substring(0, decSize.length - dec.length);
        }
        dec = dec.substring(0,9);

        return sign.concat(int, ".", dec);
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

**The PHP**

Now in PHP convert your latitude and longitude into a key in the same format. You can even work out a key for minimum latitude and minimum longitude and maximum latitude and maximum longitude so you can do a search by a "range" (Range will be a box not a circle, but good enough to narrow result set significantly)

For example:

```
$location = GeoLocation::fromDegrees($data['location']['latitude'], $data['location']['longitude']);
$coordinates = $location->boundingCoordinates(50, 'miles');

$startkey = "point::" . $location->buildKey($coordinates[0]->getLatitudeInDegrees()) . "," . $location->buildKey($coordinates[0]->getLongitudeInDegrees());
$endkey = "point::" . $location->buildKey($coordinates[1]->getLatitudeInDegrees()) . "," . $location->buildKey($coordinates[1]->getLongitudeInDegrees());

$viewOptions = array(
    'startkey' => $startkey,
    'endkey' => $endkey
);

$results = CBDatabase::$master->searchByView("dev_posts", "by_location", $viewOptions);
```

The build key function just follows the same rules as above in my view. and the GeoLocation class is taken from here: https://github.com/anthonymartin/GeoLocation.php

**Request**

I hope this really helps someone. It does work for me. If there is a much better way of doing this I'd love to hear constructive feedback.

I would now like to include a sort by date created within the range of keys. Order by Descending in the options won't work as this will order by the actual location key. The only way I can think of doing this is to include the date.created into the beginning of the key. But I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about this. I am very new to couchbase so guidance would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever considered using ElasticSearch which has a Couchbase plugin for easy replication?  ES is much better suited to GEO location problems (plus other stuff like free text search etc).

Comment: I literally just discovered ElasticSearch. I will have to do my research. See if I can find some good tutorials! Thank you for bringing this to my attention :)

Comment: This is a nice tutorial on integrating Couchbase with ElasticSearch and Kibana (GUI) http://blog.jeroenreijn.com/2013/07/visitor-analysis-with-couchbase-elasticsearch.html